# How to open alertcontroller after pressed TabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

[image]

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.delegate = self
        
        let vc1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VideoListVC())
        let vc2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: AddViewController())
        let vc3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FabricViewController())
        
        
        
        vc1.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "house")
        vc2.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "qrcode")
        vc3.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "house")
        
        
        
        //tabBar.tintColor = .label
        
        setViewControllers([vc1, vc2, vc3], animated: true)
        
        
        func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UITabBarController) {
                if viewController is AddViewController {
                    print("Alert is opened")
                
            }
       

    }
```

I can't open alertcontroller because my TabBarController is rootcontroller. How can i fix it   ?

Answer (score 0):

the didSelect method is wrong , replace with :

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if viewController is AddViewController {
            print("put code for showing alert")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cross check you delegate function with the below code

```
   func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if let vc = viewController as? UINavigationController, vc.topViewController! is AddViewController {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Since you are adding `UINavigationController` to the `UITabBarController`, so first you need to check for that inside the delegate function and then check for the rooviewcontroller of the `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score -1):

`self.show(alertController, sender: self)`

This should work as `UITabbarController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`